# Get the id of previous sibling anchor element in javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, siblings

**Solved :** to get the id of the previous element, use `previousElementSibling.id` instead of `previousSibling.id`. Thank you to Xufox and Skyline3000 who quickly provided the solution.

---

Having some breadcrumbs done of anchors elements, I'm trying to get the id of the previous sibling when one breakcrumb is clicked (i.e. the parent category).
eg. `Fruits> Apples> Green apples`

Unfortunately, my code does not work.

- `alert(this.previousSibling)` returns `[object Text]`
- `alert(this.previousSibling,id)` returns `id is undefined`.
- `alert(this.previousSibling,getAttribute(\'id\')` returns `TypeError: this.previousSibling.getAttribute is not a function`.
- `alert(this.previousSibling,attr(\'id\'))` returns `TypeError: this.previousSibling.attr is not a function`.

I assume that the sibling is not correctly reached as I was expecting some Element or Object and not Text.

Here's what the HTML and javascript of two breadcrumbs look like:

```
<a id="n5_40_64_40" onclick="javascript:
    var tree=jQuery('#tree').dynatree('getTree');
    if (!tree.activateKey('40')) {
      var parent=0;
      if (1) {
       parent=this.previousSibling.id.split(/[_]+/).pop();
      }
    }
    return false;" href="">Apples</a>
>
<a id="n5_40_64_64" onclick="javascript:
    var tree=jQuery('#tree').dynatree('getTree');
    if (!tree.activateKey('64')) {
      var parent=0;
      if (2) {
       parent=this.previousSibling.id.split(/[_]+/).pop();
      }
    }
    return false;" href="">Green apples</a>
```

Comment: _“`alert(this.previousSibling)` returns `[object Text]`”_ — use `console.log` instead. `alert` is not made for debugging. You have a `Text` node. Those don’t have IDs. Did you want `this.previousElementSibling`? Did you intend to put commas after `this.previousSibling`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware of `this.previousElementSibling` and it is exactly what I was looking for. With it, the code then correctly sets the `parent`. Now, I don't understand the purpose of `this.previousSibling`. From this example, I was expecting it pointing to an HTML element: `var x = document.getElementById("item2").previousSibling.innerHTML;`. I did not intend to put commas after `this.previousSibling`. The `split().pop()` is to retrieve the id of the clicked breadcrumb because in `id="..."`I had to prefix it with the path to obtain an ID that is unique in the HTML document.

Comment: Also see skyline3000's answer which is self-explanatory about what `this.previousSibling` was retrieving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All text and whitespace, including whitespace and new lines between your HTML tags, count as a [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). Thus the tag's previous sibling is actual the textNode of whitespace between the `<a>` tags. What you really want to do is find the previous sibling that is an element (HTML tag).

For that you should simply use [this.previousElementSibling](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling.html).

Comment: You perfectly understood what I wanted. Thank you for the clarity of your answer, which also explains what `this.previousSibling` was retrieving: whitespace.